# Cannot create provisioning profile for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to make a new build of an iOS app and upload it to the App Store. The provisioning profile has expired. I get also errors

> No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
>   No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "TeamID" with a private key was found.

and

> No profile for team "TeamID" matching 'iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile' found
>   Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'TeamID/iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile'.

The app in itunesconnect is connected to a team that I don't see in developer.apple.com . The app is also not visible there and I cannot create the needed provisioning profile. For the same reason I cannot create the provisioning profile with Automatically managed signing.

Does this mean I don't have access / rights in developer.apple.com to this app? Or I am completely misunderstanding what is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are connected on xcode with the good team profile. go to app dev center and go in manage (for your app) and you can add / delete or recreate a new one

Comment: @tetar Thanks for your reply. I don't have this team listed in Xcode and I cannot link to it. The app is also not visible for me in the dev center.

Comment: are you sure to be on the team ?

Comment: you can create a new team or/and recreate a provisioning profile

Comment: @tetar I am not sure if I am on the team. I see the team only in itunesconnect, but not in the developer center. As far as I understand if I create a new team or choose another team, I will need to register the app again with another bundle id

Comment: if you are not in the team you should ask to be part of the team else you should create a new team

Answer (score 0):

First, login with your apple developer credentials and see the development certificate and profile status. As per your question, it seems that your membership for apple developer account has expired, You need to renew your account. Once you renew your account your app will shown in app store, may be take some time to refresh on all stores.

However in this case you push notification services will not worked because of expiring these certifcates too.

You need to create new developer and distribution certificates, pem files and provisioning profiles so you can run your app in your device from xcode. Submit the pem file to backend.

By submitting the new distribution pem file on backend, they will update it and your push notification services will be worked on live app also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am part of couple of teams in the developer center and with the rest everything is okay. But for this specific team I have no access to certificates, identifiers & profiles. I don't see it - the team - in the developer center either, only in itunesconnect. Does this mean that the person responsible for this team (the account holder) has to renew their membership?

Comment: As per your comment you need to communicate with that team, because that team admin has given you access rights for iTunes not developer account